# Setting up mail client on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, email, mutt, mta

I want to use command line mail client on the basic installation of Arch Linux, either mail or mutt or some other utility. I read that these are only mail clients means along with them we have to also install mail transfer agents. I tried to configure exim but that did not work out. Is there any other utility which can be easily configured and how to configure it ?

Answer (score 7):

Postfix is quite easy to configure, especially for relaying through a "smarthost" (Gmail or ISP or whatever).

---

Configuring Postfix for Gmail:

1. Update `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

   ```
   compatibility_level = 2
   inet_interfaces = loopback-only
   relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
   # NOTE: the CAfile/CApath is distro-dependent!
   smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
   smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
   smtp_tls_security_level = verify
   smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
   smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
   ```
2. Create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`:

   ```
   [smtp.gmail.com]:587     joe@gmail.com:JoesSekritPassword
   ```
3. Run as root:

   ```
   postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
   chmod 640 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd*
   chgrp postfix /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd*
   ```
4. Tell Postfix to reload configuration:

   ```
   postfix reload
   ```

---

Exim is not bad either, as long as you ignore all the Debian-specific tutorials and their macros nonsense.

There also are `msmtp` and `esmtp`, which can *only* use a smarthost and so don't need to be run as a daemon. They also are much easier to configure, *especially* for multi-user environments.

---

If you are looking for the `mail` command, make sure you get either `heirloom-mailx` or GNU `mailutils`. (The classic `bsd-mailx` works, but it lacks many features such as Maildir or MIME support.) I still prefer mutt, though.

Comment: Could you provide me the link to configure PostFix for  Gmail?

Comment: @pineapple: See edited answer, or google `postfix gmail`. (Btw, it's "Postfix", not "PostFix.")

Comment: I configured the Postfix as you mentioned. But when I send mails using mutt or sendmail,they show no error but I am not receiving any mails in gmail. I want to know how to check the status of mail whether it was delivered or not. Also using sendmail, I sent mail like this: sendmail <id>
and then typed the body and pressed Ctrl D. Is this the correct way?
When using mutt, it says mail sent. But when I open mutt for the first time,it says /var/spool/mail/root:No such file or directory
I want to confirm that I only want to configure postfix for outgoing mails.I don want to fetch mails from gmail.

Comment: @pineapple: No, it's not the correct way to use `sendmail` -- it expects to be called from a mail client and given a full RFC-(2)822 message, incl. headers. You should use `mail <addr>` or `mutt <addr>` instead. // However, a good MTA will send the message anyway -- so please check the Postfix queue (`mailq`) and the system logs (`sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log`) for any error messages.

Comment: @grawity See the suggested edit, please review if that's correct or requires any additional comment.

Comment: @slhck: The edit is correct, but I didn't see the need for the added option, given that the server (Gmail) does not offer such authentication mechanisms anyway; even if it did, Postfix *should* attempt stronger mechanisms first. But if it fixes auth problems for someone, it can stay.

Comment: +1 this is still very actual, even though postifx was updated several times...  One question, I am weary of a password remaining in clear text in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`. Is there a way to hash that or obfuscate the password somehow ? Merely changing file access permission falls very short of that.

Comment: @Cbhihe: No, because you'll have to _send_ it to Gmail in plain text. You can create an "app password" if you use 2fa (well, have to), or ask the Gmail developers to support something like SCRAM-SHA-1 (which allows storing a hash), or ask the Postfix developers to support Google OAUTH (which allows storing a token).

Comment: Mmmh, asking any dev anything, anywhere, out of the blue seems like a veeeery long shot, if my experience serves. So I'm thinking more of a hack (in the form of a wrapper) that would allow users to enter their gmail password on the fly rather than have it permanently stored in `/etc/postfix/sasl_password` or anywhere. But that'd be impractical at best. Thanks for yr answer anyway. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Cbhihe: Then I don't think you should use postfix for Gmail relaying at all. Have each user configure msmtp individually, with their own accounts in ~/.msmtprc.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things you need for basic email:

- a program to **format RFC 822 email** that you are about to send
- a program to **send (RFC 822) formatted emails** to your mail relay/submission system over SMTP (mail submission agent — MSA, or mail transfer agent — MTA)
- a program to **access your remote mailbox** for things like remotely saved drafts, your inbox, etc. by using IMAP, POP, SMAP, rsyncing to a local mbox or maildir, or even just using `sshfs` to make the said mbox or maildir available on the filesystem (mail user agent — MUA, usually bundles the first component)

If you see the term 'mail delivery agent' (MDA), ignore it. That's a server-side program program for those creating their own service.

You likely already have the MUA (`mutt`, `mailx`, `alpine`, etc.), as well as the third component. The MSA **likely** is also built into the same program that is your MUA. Take a look at the following.

- For example, for, the offical Arch Linux `mutt` package, in the simplest configuration (see `muttrc(5)`):

  ```
  # MUA part
  set folder = "imaps://foo@example.com" # shortcut so that I can use relative
                                     # names for $spoolfile, etc.
  set spoolfile = "=INBOX"
  set record = "=Sent Messages"
  set postponed = "=Drafts"

  set from = "foo@example.com"

  # MSA/MTA part
  set smtp_url = "smtp://foo@example.com" # or `foo@example.com@example.com`
                                          # if the server requires a fully
                                          # qualified user name, say because it
                                          # serves multiple domains
  ```
- I've never used alpine but the Arch Wiki has a [page on it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alpine).
- For mailx (`heirloom-mailx` package, I believe the following `~/.mailrc` (see `mailx(1)`) will do. Use `mailx -A example.com` to tell mailx to use that account.

  ```
  account example.com {
      set folder=imaps://foo@example.com
      set imap-auth=login
      set record=+Sent
          set 

      set smtp=example.com
      set smtp-auth=plain # or whatever your server uses
      set smtp-auth-user=foo

      set from="foo@example.com (Foo Bar)"
      set hostname=example.com
  }
  ```

Now, read on if you still want to use the traditional standalone MTA method. Since most traditional MUAs like mutt or mailx can use the `sendmail` interface (i.e., they just pipe mail to the `sendmail` binary, and you're *only* sending mail, not setting up a full-blown mail server, use the [Dragonfly Mail Agent](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dma/), rather than downloading a full server (like Postfix or sendmail). It's in the AUR. It just works and is only running when you actually send mail (i.e., it's not a deamon). It provides a wrapper binary at `/usr/bin/sendmail`. There's no configuration, assuming you're using an open relay. If you are using a relay that requires SMTP AUTH (you may often hear the term SASL, which is partially accurate), you can do something like what follows:

File `/etc/dma/auth.conf`:

```
some user|some mail relay or submission system:password
```

File `/etc/dma/dma.conf` (in addition to what is already in there by default):

```
SMARTHOST=hostname or IP address of smarthost or submission system or mail relay
```

You may have to configure your MUAs accordingly though. If I recall correctly, `mailx` and `mutt` need no additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Vmail](http://danielchoi.com/software/vmail.html) is pretty good, although I don't believe we can shoot files around from within scripts... like my favorite trick of sending myself email notifications when a job is complete.  But if you're just looking for a text-based front end for Gmail, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

ssmtp is a very lightweight, easy-to-configure MTA.